# async-await callback behaviour

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, async-await

I'm trying to understand async-await behaviour with callbacks. Firstly, let's look at this function:

```
const assert = require('assert')

async function promiseReturner() {
  return Promise.resolve(Promise.resolve(Promise.resolve(Promise.resolve(42))))
}

(async function() {
  assert.equal(await promiseReturner(), 42)
})()
```

This leads me to safely conclude that the `await` keyword always resolves a promise, no matter what.

Now here's a function that returns a number after a second:

```
async function addTenAndReturnNumber(number) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve(number)
    }, 1000)
  })
}
```

I ran two experiments with this. First the forEach loop.

```
(async function() {
  let variable;
  const result = [41, 42, 43].forEach(async (number) => {
    variable = await addTenAndReturnNumber(number)
  })
  console.log(variable) // undefined
})()
```

Okay, so great. It would appear that the forEach callback evaluated in the next tick, and hence `variable` is undefined (although that's exactly what one would think `await` shouldn't do). Let's try `map` next:

```
(async function() {
  const result = [41, 42, 43].map(async (number) => {
    return await addTenAndReturnNumber(number)
  })
  console.log(result) // [Promise {}, Promise {}, Promise {}]
})()
```

I would assume that it would either return `[51, 52, 53]`, or as before an `undefined`

Please note that my question is around the behaviour and why this is designed like so - is this a conscious decision on the part of the spec? I am aware that I can use a `for...of` or a `Promise.all`

Thanks!

Comment: The `await` keyword never returns a promise.  Do you mean `async`?

Comment: Well, I mean that `await` always returns the result of a promise (maybe resolve is a wrong choice of words?)

Comment: Remove the `async` in front of `addTenAndReturnNumber()`. You are basically encapsulating a promise within a promise there.

Comment: @KarthikIyengar: Yes; `await` returns the value of a promise.   So what?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`async` functions always return a promise (if you `await` the promise, you'll get its actual value).

Passing an `async` function to `map()` will return an array of what the `async` function returns, which is, of course, a promise.

Your `forEach()` callback runs immediately, but once it hits the `await`, it will only resume running after the promise resolves (which is guaranteed to be after your code finishes running).

Comment: Could you please elaborate on why the variable in the forEach example is not set to a 43?

Comment: @KarthikIyengar: Why would it be set to a promise? You never assign it to anything that can be a promise.

Comment: I get it now. Thanks and apologies for the dumbness :-)